# how to add a onclick even on tables in ASP so that you can do something from the c# backend

Tags: c#, asp.net

i have this piece  of code

```
<asp:Table ID="Table1" runat="server">
    <asp:TableRow>
        <asp:TableCell>
         Cell text
        </asp:TableCell>
    </asp:TableRow>
</asp:Table>
```

what i want to do is to make this table clicable and to process somthing at the back for example

```
void Table1_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //do somthing
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you not add an onclick event to the table? Like this. It has been a while since I did webforms.

```
<asp:Table id="Table1" runat="server" OnClick="Table1_Click">
    <asp:TableRow>
      <asp:TableCell>
         Cell text
      </asp:TableCell>
    </asp:TableRow>
</asp:Table>
```

Then use what you have for your backend.

```
void Table1_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //do somthing
}
```

Comment: No, you cannot. It will not trigger a PostBack.

Comment: @VDWWD you are right. Like I said it has been a while. I had it in my head that the runat would run the event at the server level.

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap the entire Table with a LinkButton.

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" OnClick="Button1_Click">

    <asp:Table ID="Table1" runat="server">
        <asp:TableRow>
            <asp:TableCell>
                 Cell text
            </asp:TableCell>
        </asp:TableRow>
    </asp:Table>

</asp:LinkButton>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest creating a JavaScript function and then making an Ajax call to a web method to call CS method.

HTML:

```
<asp:Table ID="Table1" runat="server">
    <asp:TableRow >
        <asp:TableCell onclick="tablecell_click();">
            hello
        </asp:TableCell>
    </asp:TableRow>
</asp:Table>
```

Javascript:

```
function tablecell_click() {
        //JQuery ajax call here
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

`in Jquery:

$(document).ready(function(){

$("#Table1").on('click',function(){

alert();
  });
});`

Answer (score 0):

Create a button and use JQuery to click the button to do the PostBack. Call the JQuery using the onclick on the TableCell

```
 <asp:Table ID="Table1" runat="server">
    <asp:TableRow>
        <asp:TableCell onclick="tablecell_click();">
            hello
        </asp:TableCell>
   </asp:TableRow>
</asp:Table>
<asp:Button runat="server" id="btnCellClick" OnClick="Table1_Click"/>

    <script>
        function tablecell_click() {
           $('#btnCellClick').click();
         }
   </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The `asp:Repeater` control is what you need:

https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Repeater-control-Tutorial-with-example-in-ASPNet-using-C-and-VBNet.aspx